# Is there something like GraphEdit for MediaFoundation?

Tags: ms-media-foundation, graphedit

[GraphEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphEdit) only works for [DirectShow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and not for topologies built using [MediaFoundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Is there a similar tool as GraphEdit for MediaFoundation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similarly to GraphEdit, [TopoEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485862(v=vs.85).aspx) is a visual tool for building and testing MediaFoundation topologies.

TopoEdit is available in the [Windows SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8279), starting with the Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 (remember to tick *Tools* checkbox).

By default it installs to: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin`

Comment: Note that TopoEdit lacks a critical feature: the ability to connect to an external graph in order to debug code that you write.  
  
To debug Media Foundation Code that you write, you will need to become familiar with MFTRACE.  See Roman Ryltsov's answer, here:  
  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21151028/can-topoedit-be-used-to-load-a-topology-for-a-session-created-by-my-application

Answer (score 1):

If you install the newest Windows SDK. You can find the TopoEdit sample code in:

```
Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Samples\Multimedia\MediaFoundation
```